# overlapping labels in graphviz

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I tried to code formal concept example with python,
When I tried to visualize lattice with Graphviz I got overlapping labels ?

Any solution to that ?

My code:

```
from concepts import Context
c = Context.fromstring('''
            |ahpo:sentTo: Eugénie Launois|dcterms:subject: Affaires diverses (polytechnique)|dcterms:subject: Affaire des postards|dcterms:subject: Visites familiales et amicales|dcterms:subject: Candidature à l’École normale supérieure (1873)|dcterms:subject: Colles et examens (polytechnique)|dcterms:subject|ahpo:citeName: Albert Badoureau|ahpo:citeName: Emmanuel Ruault|ahpo:citeName: Louis Émile Maniguet|
 item/12531 |  X                         |  X                                               |                                     |                                               |                                                                |                                                  | X             |  X                            |                              |                                   |         
 item/3874  |  X                         |  X                                               |  X                                  | X                                             |                                                                |                                                  | X             |  X                            | X                            | X                                 |
 item/12546 |  X                         |                                                  |  X                                  | X                                             |                                                                |                                                  | X             |  X                            |                              |                                   |
 item/12551 |  X                         |  X                                               |  X                                  | X                                             |                                                                |                                                  | X             |  X                            | X                            |                                   |
 item/3671  |  X                         |                                                  |  X                                  |                                               | X                                                              |                                                  | X             |  X                            | X                            | X                                 |
 item/3995  |  X                         |                                                  |  X                                  | X                                             | X                                                              | X                                                | X             |                               | X                            |                                   |
 item/4107  |  X                         |                                                  |                                     |                                               |                                                                |                                                  | X             |                               |                              |                                   |
 ''')

c.lattice.graphviz(view=True)
```

[overlap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsLsz.png)

Comment: Do you know which Graphviz engine this is using?  (dot, neato, fdp, ...)

Comment: @sroush 
<graphviz.dot.Digraph object at 0x...>
I executed this example: 
https://pypi.org/project/concepts/#:~:text=Make%20a%20Graphviz%20visualization%20of%20the%20lattice%20(use%20.graphviz(view%3DTrue)%20to%20directly%20render%20it%20and%20display%20the%20resulting%20PDF)%3A

Did I answered to your question ?

Comment: This really seems to be a "concepts" question (as opposed to python , jupyter, or graphviz).  Have you tried asking on their website?